# The meaning of shorthand charaters of TFS user name on codeplex.com

Tags: codeplex

I notice that my TFS user name on codeplex.com is in the form of snd\_cp.

I don't know what the shorthands `snd` and `cp` stand for?

My guess:

- *snd* is the domain name of the user account so I can guess 'd' is for domain, and 'sn' is for `s`ubversio`n` :D
- *cp* is `c`ode`p`lex

How about you?